# Retrieve all data under Uid Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello guys I am new to Firebase and I am trying to retrieve all data under Uid.
I store them like this:

```
mDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Data").child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
//some other code here
 DatabaseReference newProduct =mDatabase.child(category).child("Product").push();
 newProduct.child("productname").setValue(name);
 newProduct.child("date").setValue(date);
```

My question is how can I retrieve all data under userUid category? Do I need something like `.child(*).child("Products")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is use a listener to retrieve that data, something along the lines of

```
 mDatabase.child(category).child("Product").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                 String name = (String) dataSnapshot.child("productname").getValue;
                 String date = (String) dataSnapshot.child("date").getValue;


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

There you go, now you pulled all that data as Strings.

Also, I would suggest that instead of

```
auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()
```

use

```
String uid = (String) auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

and just put uid in there instead, that way your code is much cleaner and everytime you need to refer to uid, you have a string for it.

Comment: Should it be: String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(); ?

Comment: It's the same. He did it that way: 

FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
String uid = (String) auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();